# auto download by using recordRTC when we click the stop button

Tags: javascript, php, screen-recording, recordrtc

I am using this source code https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/simple-demos/screen-recording.html

to screen recording, it is working fine and after clicking stop button we can see our recorded video and then we can download the video by clicking download option at video.

Instead of manually download, is there any way auto download like If I click stop button the video can download automatically  into my `download` folder.

what I have tried: in `stopRecordingCallback()` function

```
var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(recorder.getBlob()); 
     reader.onloadend = function() {
         var base64data = reader.result;                
        console.log(base64data);
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'save.php',
                data: {base64data: base64data},              
                success: function(msg) {
               
                   // alert('Successfully uploaded.');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                    alert('Error:' + JSON.stringify(errorMessage));
                }
          });               
     }
```

Problem is ,it is working fine in my localhost and i can download the video automatically but when I update this code into my server it is not working ,I got this `error:Request Entity Too Large` ,I am changed my code in init.php file

```
#set max post size
post_max_size = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 512M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

I am sending my data by using `POST` only.

still I am getting same error ,so instead of this ,is there any way to download automatically that video.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to accomplish this yourself?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius ,Thanks for you response,I have added my code kinldy check once .Thanks